# python - Splitting nested dictionary for export into excel with subheaders

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{"summary":
 {"MemberID":"73164",
  "JoinDate":"2017-05-23",
  "class":"15-05",
  "status":"Registered",
  "confirmedDate":"2017-05-26",
  "referral":null,
  "renewalDate":"2020-05-23",
 },

 "member":
 [{"memberCode":"njdskadh",
   "name":"masked",
   "address":"masked",
   "country":
{"code":"JP",
 "description":"Japan"},
  }],

 "license":null,

 "Interest":null,

 "documents":
  [{"fileDate":"2017-05-23",
"fileId":"dkasdh7482121",
"fileName":"dajkgdh.jpg",
"fileUrl":"https://mask.api/file/dajkgdh",
"docType":{"code":"hsjas","description":"Images"}},

   {"fileDate":"2017-07-23",
"fileId":"dkasdh74823473841",
"fileName":"FFG.txt",
"fileUrl":"https://mask.api/file/FFG",
"docType":{"code":"hsjas","description":"text"}}]}
```

Above is a truncated and anonymized version of the return value i got from calling an API. It is in the format of a dictionary of nested dictionaries and list. I would need to somehow extract the information into excel, grouped into headers (e.g. summary, member, license) and subheaders (e.g. MemberID, JoinDate) which each of these headers have.

Oddly, there are certain fields (e.g. member) where the return value seems to be a list of dictionary. I am wondering if i should clean up the [ ] first as well.

Another problem is also the documents header, where there are multiple documents with the same subheaders.

The ultimate goal is to run a loop and append subsequent return values from the API call onto this master list.

I am not very certain if headers, subheaders is the correct thinking or should i be doing separate sheets and headers instead (in this case i would need MemberID from the first sheet as an index identifier).

Thank you.

[How the excel looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W7Yv.png)

Comment: Could you show how you want you excel file to look like? Also why not just put into a csv file?

Comment: I have amended the post to include a sample of how the excel could look like.

Comment: Anyone can help ? Still an ongoing problem.